# 2 For-Loops with chars is skipping a lot of the outpurs

Tags: java, for-loop

I am attempting to have a java program output every combination of two characters. I made code like this:

```
package foo;

public class CombineChars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(char a = '0'; a <= 'z'; a++){
            for(char b = '0'; b <= 'z'; b++){
                System.out.println(a+b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect is an output that looks like this:

```
00
01
02...
10
11
```

etc. But I get:

```
96 (First value)
97
98...
(Fluctuates here with going to like 220 then down to 150)
(Ends on) 244
```

Why does it do this and how can I fix it? Also I am open if there are better ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's converting the `char`s to `int`s and adding as numbers.

If you want to do `String` concatenation you have to do

```
a + "" + b
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You are performing integer math here,

```
System.out.println(a + b);
```

convert one (or both) arguments to a `String`. Like,

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(a) + b);
```